# Month to QTR formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Hire Month column that is a text entry. I cannot be a full date.  I want to have a another column for QTR and whatever month is in the Hire month, convert to 1, 2, 3 or 4 in the QTR column.  How do I do that?

[image: rwn]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: The reason we don't like images of data or code is that we have to retype everything in order to work on the data....

Comment: Having said that please see [formula to convert month to quarter](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1059149-formula-to-convert-month-to-quarter.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a version of Excel that supports dynamic arrays, you can use this (supposing your month were in column A):

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,{3,6,9,12},{1,2,3,4},"",1,2)
```

In other words, take the month and look for it in the first array. Find the month exactly or the next largest number in the array and return the item from the second array whose position is the position found previously. Return an empty string if the month isn't found.

EDIT:

since your month is currently text, then use this instead:

```
=XLOOKUP(MONTH(1&A1),{3,6,9,12},{1,2,3,4},"",1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Math:

```
=INT((MONTH(1&A2)-1)/3)+1
```

which is similar to one of the answer in the [Linked](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1059149-formula-to-convert-month-to-quarter.html) site in the comments